# Linq join with dictionary and value type key in xamarin ios

Tags: c#, linq, generics, dictionary, xamarin.ios

I have a Dictonary and a IEnumerable that I would like to join on Key and OtherThing.Id

This works fine with a simple linq join on Xamarin Monodroid. Then we wanted to use our code in the IO's App. It threw an exception and I quickly figured out why. As explained in Xamarin Docs, I don't can use Generic Dictionaries with value types.

I Then tried the workaround explained on the Xamarin docs in chapter 1.7 ([find here](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/limitations)) and passing a own implementation of IEqualityComparer to the constructor of the Dictionary like:

Comperator:

```
public class EqualityComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<T>
{
    #region IEqualityComparer implementation

    public bool Equals (T x, T y)
    {
        return x.Equals (y);
    }

    public int GetHashCode (T obj)
    {
        return obj.GetHashCode ();
    }

    #endregion

}
```

And pass it to the Dictionary

```
Dictionary<Int32, Attempt> allAttempts = 
new Dictionary<int, Attempt>(new EqualityComparer<int>());

allAttempts.Add (1, new Attempt () {Id=1, Name="attempt for 1"} );
allAttempts.Add (2, new Attempt () {Id=2, Name="attempt for 2"} );
```

But the error seems to be caused in the join so I tried to provide the Comparer also to the join:

```
var result = conditions.Join(
attempts,
c => c.Id,
cA => cA.Key,
(c, cA) => cA.Value,
new EqualityComparer<Int32> ());
```

But this also gives me still the following exception:

```
got this: System.ExecutionEngineException: Attempting to JIT compile method         'System.Linq.Enumerable/Function1<System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair2>:m__56 (System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2)' while running with --aot-only. 
See http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/about/limitations for more information. 

at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToLookupKeyValuePair2,Int32,KeyValuePair2<IEnumerable%601%20source,%20System.Func%602%20keySelector,%20System.Func%602%20elementSelector,%20IEqualityComparer%601%20comparer> [0x00079]
in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/System.Core/System.Linq/Enumerable.cs:2977
at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToLookupKeyValuePair`2,Int32<IEnumerable%601%20source,%20System.Func%602%20keySelector,%20IEqualityComparer%601%20comparer> [0x00000] 
in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/System.Core/System.Linq/Enumerable.cs:2945 
at System.Linq.Enumerable+c__Iterator184[Drallo.ChallengeEngine.Condition,System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair2[System.Int32,Drallo.ChallengeEngine.Attempt.ConditionAttempt],System.Int32,Drallo.ChallengeEngine.Attempt.ConditionAttempt].MoveNext () [0x00023] 
in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/System.Core/System.Linq/Enumerable.cs:1157
```

Here you can find a test project for ios I've set up to reproduce this problem:
https://github.com/stestaub/TestLinqJoins/blob/master/TestLinqJoins/JoinWithDictionary.cs

Whats the problem about in this case and how can I solve this/avoid in the future? I'd still prefer to use linq.

Thank You for any help and hints

Comment: Based on your exception being a JIT failure that specifically references Xamarin, wouldn't you increase your likeliness of an answer by posting on Xamarin's forum?

Comment: Your right, I'm so used to find very good answers on stackoverflow that I didn't consider to ask elsewhere :)

Comment: If you can reproduce it easily in a new project, the best thing is to submit a bug to http://bugzilla.xamarin.com for JIT issues. If you need an immediate fix, the best thing is to write your code in a slightly different way. I think it's fine to ask Xamarin questions here BTW.